# PHP - weird timezone offset

Tags: php, timezone, offset

I'm encountering a stupid problem which I just cannot understand.
How come that following piece of code:

```
public function getFormattedOffsetFrom($refTimezoneId = 'Europe/Paris', $format = 'G\hi') {
    $timestamp = time();
    $reference = new DateTime('@'.$timestamp);
    $referenceTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($refTimezoneId);
    $reference->setTimezone($referenceTimeZone);
    $datetime = new DateTime('@'.$timestamp);
    $datetime->setTimezone($this->timezone);
    $offset = $this->timezone->getOffset($datetime) - $referenceTimeZone->getOffset($reference);
    $prefix = '+';
    if($offset < 0) {
        $prefix = '-';
        $offset = abs($offset);
    }
    return $prefix.date($format, $offset);
}
```

where $this->timezone is an instance of DateTimeZone positioned in Europe/Madrid, produces +1h00 when no args are specified ????

Paris and Madrid have no time offset. I just don't understand.

Thanks a lot for your help !!!!
Florent

Comment: ahh, you are comparing Paris *against* Madrid, sorry, I didn't get that. Can you output the raw offsets to see what's wrong? It might be an error inside the function

Comment: well, the offset should be 0 :)

Comment: I think you'll have to debug the function and see where it goes wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Why should be 0 ? Both Spain and France are using GMT+1 as time zone.</del>

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Time_zones_of_Europe.svg

The problem is that you are trying to format `$offset` that holds time difference in seconds, with function `date()`, which expects timestamp as second parameter. If the `$offset == 0` `date` function recognizes it as **1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT**, so in your timezone it will be **1970-01-01 01:00:00 GMT+1**, and you are using format to return hours and minutes so that is why you have +1 as output.

You have to manually format this time difference like this:

```
$offsetH = floor( $offset / 3600 ); //full hours
$offsetM = floor(($offset - $offsetH) / 60 ); //full minutes

return sprintf("%s%sh%02s",$prefix,$offsetH,$offsetM) ;
```

Comment: He is comparing  Paris *against* Madrid, I made the same mistake at first

Comment: Equivalent to `sprintf('%+03dh:%02um', $offset / 3600, $offset % 3600 / 60);`.

Comment: @Alix Axel - nice one-liner, but I don't think that representing minutes as unsigned long will give desired results for negative offsets. [edit] Just checked to be sure - yup it does not prints absolute value, still need to use `abs()` on second variable

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: Oh, yes the modulo operator in PHP acts strangely with negative numbers, `sprintf('%+03dh:%02um', $offset / 3600, abs($offset) % 3600 / 60);` is the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reduced to `date('G', 0)` giving "1". Solution is to use `gmdate()`.